# How to insert NS Mutable Array into Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

```
-(void)dataManagerDidFinishLoading:(DataManager *)datamgr
{
    NSLog(@"%@.....",datamgr);

    pageArray=[datamgr.resultDataDictionary objectForKey:@"POS_GetPageResult"];
    GetPage *page=(GetPage *)[NSEntityDescription 
                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"GetPage" 
                         inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

   NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // This is a serious error saying the record could not be saved.
        // Advise the user to restart the application
        NSLog(@"Error........");
    }

    [pageArray insertObject:page atIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSKeyedArchiver:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

Note that all the objects in array must conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. If these are custom objects, then that means you need to read up on [Encoding and Decoding Objects](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Tasks/codingobjects.html). You can store the `NSData` as `BLOB` in the database. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transformable core data type. Then your object will be parsed to an id. Just keep in mind that the transformable attribute will be passed to a NSData object (and reversed) to be stored (or retrieved) in core data.